# How to frequently switch internet connection without troubleshooting

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have an Asus strix GL753V laptop running windows 10. As part of my job I have to keep switching between the internet connection of the office and mobile hotspot in order to test things locally and on the internet.

Every time I switch to another network, it says no internet, I have to go through windows troubleshooter to reset the wifi manager and then try again.

That's only happens when I switch fast, not when I connect casually, how to fix that?

Comment: maybe some command that changes priorities of things in the routing table though not sure. This might help https://www.raymond.cc/blog/choosing-which-connection-to-use-with-windows-routing-table-editor-gui/

Comment: Did you try running ipconfig /release and ipconfig /renew when you switch networks? I seem to have to run those commands every single time I connect to my mobile hotspot.

Comment: @JerryHundric thanks for the tip, when I go to work, I'll try that and report back

Comment: @JerryHundric worth noting that with the method I mention, he won't have to disconnect

Comment: @JerryHundric maybe you should try what lynob does! I've found the troubleshooter /repair works sometimes when ipconfig /release and renew doesn't..  Have you ever found release renew work when the troubleshooter doesn't? I haven't. I've found the troubleshooter / repair, to be better. in win7 anyway.

Comment: @barlop I usually don't use the troubleshooter because it is just too slow for me. I always resort to other much quicker methods instead. /release and /renew is just one of them (in fact, I usually use them in a script and then just run the script). I think that if the troubleshooter resets the adapter, then /release and /renew won't work either because when the troubleshooter resets the adapter, it seems to include whatever /release and /renew does (I just tested it).

Comment: @barlop But I agree with you that in Windows 7 (in fact, starting from Windows Vista) that the troubleshooter is great. It solved all of my networking problems until I started knowing my full way around networking in Windows.

Comment: @JerryHundric  I told you the troubleshooter (or right clicking and clicking repair, )can do more than release and renew, and I gave the example of how for me it has fixed things that those didnt. So it's that and more.